# How to handle a new activity which gets launch over android app in your automation scripts of appium

Tags: android, mobile, appium

We have a new functionality in our app in which a new activity prompts while navigating through the app....

Handling of this activity is easy if we know the event , for which this activity will fire and display on app...

But my problem is I do not know when this activity will fire while navigating through app.

Basically we have a company  dashboard on which rule get changes frequently by marketing team and this activity will keep changing 
Some time activity will display on listing page and sometime on product details page as per rules changes

Please let me know ideas/solutions, if anyone else face the same problem statement in there test automation scripts also while using appium[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCIfD.png)

Attaching screenshot for reference

Comment: Your question not very clear , how is it related with appium?

Comment: @DineshBalu : Updated the title,Please read the body ...of question ,it will help you to understand my query